# C#: вопрос по массиву байтов

Tags: c#, конвертация, hex

HEX-редактор мне выдал массив байтов: {0x30,0x31,0x02}

Я хочу записать эти данные хардкорно в массив:

```
byte[] arr = {a,b,c};
```

Можно ли  мне вместе `a,b,c` записать 30, 31, 02 соответственно, или мне нужно какие-то операции провести с этими числами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам именно вот так, с префиксом `0x` и надо записать:

```
byte[] arr = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x02 };
```

или в полной форме:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x31, 0x02 };
```

`0x` означает шестнадцатиричные числа, без префикса числа будут интерпретированы как десятичные.

Comment: подскажите, если есть строка "0х36" - как ее в байт можно переконвертить?  спасибо.

Comment: @LeonardBertone Литерал сам скастуется к байту, если число поместится в байт. Не нужно ничего конвертировать. *проверяет* Гы. Ошибка компиляции. Ща... Обновил.

Comment: у меня получается строка "363132343536" хочу уу а массив байтов запихнуть. Есть идеи как паре чисел можно приписать "0х" ?

Comment: @LeonardBertone Не понял. Какая строка? Что в ней? Куда запихнуть? В каком виде? Что, куда и зачем приписать?

Comment: Хеш-эдитор мне выдал для чисел 6123456 следующую последовательность -36 31 32 34 35 36 (примерно, не придирайтесь). Мне нужно сделать массив байтов, чтобы в каждом его элементы была одна пара чисел, т.е. byte [arr2] = {0x36, 0x31... 0x36}

Comment: @LeonardBertone Так, и в чём проблема? `byte[] arr = { 0x36, ..., 0x36 }`?

Comment: дело в том, что есть строка этих чисел "36...36". Я беру первые два символа ("36"), и мне надо превратить эти "36" в 0х36 ! С этим проблема